# Simulating default keypress behaviors in js/jquery no event listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a specific situation where I need to cause all default behaviors for the enter key press to occur. even using something like

```
var e = $.Event( "keypress", { which: 13 } );
$(".GravityTypingPrompt-input").trigger(e);
```

it doesn't trigger the event I'm looking for (a submit-style thing)
Odd facts:

> 1. the input box is a `<textarea>` not an `<input>`
> 2. Neither it nor any parents have event listeners for keypresses
> 3. I'm reverse engineering this so I have no idea what the original code was - it's been minified

If anyone wants to try it out, the link is [Here](https://quizlet.com/78973961/gravity)
I've looked through other posts about this, even ones about simulating a keypress, but I haven't found anything directly related to this topic